# C# Converting delphi TColor to color (Hex)

Tags: c#, delphi, colors, hex

[image]

These numbers are stored in the Database. They origionate from Delphi code. Although I assume they follow some kind of standard. I have tried `Color.FromArgb(255);`

But i know for a fact that the first is RED (in the delphi side), where as in ASP.NET it thinks its blue `Color [A=0, R=0, G=0, B=255]`

I want these numbers into Hexidecimal anyway. I.e. #000000 , #FFFF99 etc etc

**Anyone know how to conver these Integers (see DB Picture) to Hexidecimal.**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Delphi colors (`TColor`) are `XXBBGGRR` when not from a palette or a special color.

See [this article](http://www.acasystems.com/en/color-picker/faq-delphi-tcolor.htm) for more detail on the format (And other special cases). [The article](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.TColor) pointed by [Christian.K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21567/christian-k) also contains some details on the special cases.

## Standard colors

To convert to a standard color you should use something like :

```
var color = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, c & 0xFF, (c >> 8) & 0xFF, (c >> 16) & 0xFF);
```

To convert to hex, :

```
string ColorToHex(Color color)
{
    return string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}",
        color.R, color.G, color.B);
}
```

## System colors

For system colors (negative values in your database), they are simply the windows constants masked by `0x80000000`.

*Thanks to [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) for the info.*

## Sample code

```
Color DelphiColorToColor(uint delphiColor)
{
    switch((delphiColor >> 24) & 0xFF)
    {
        case 0x01: // Indexed
        case 0xFF: // Error
            return Color.Transparent;

        case 0x80: // System
            return Color.FromKnownColor((KnownColor)(delphiColor & 0xFFFFFF));

        default:
            var r = (int)(delphiColor & 0xFF);
            var g = (int)((delphiColor >> 8) & 0xFF);
            var b = (int)((delphiColor >> 16) & 0xFF);
            return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
    }
}

void Main()
{
    unchecked
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DelphiColorToColor((uint)(-2147483646)));
        Console.WriteLine(DelphiColorToColor(
                (uint)KnownColor.ActiveCaption | 0x80000000
            ));
        Console.WriteLine(DelphiColorToColor(0x00FF8000));
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way to convert a system color to RGB is to do like the VCL does. Call [`GetSysColor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371(v=vs.85).aspx) passing `c & 0x000000FF`. In other words, these are not VCL defined, they are *system* defined.

Comment: @David, in your comment you provided the exact answer, by don't you post it as answer?

Comment: @PA. The comment is only a small part of the answer. I'm hoping that VirtualBlackFox will incorporate the suggestion into this answer and so be able to remove the rather long and tiresome list.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't realize that it was simply the windows constants converted to TColor, thanks a lot, i'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Absolutely amazing. The red is now working. Along with all the other ones. This answer is one of the best I have seen. Very well layed out, easy to read, and easy to follow. I wouldnt have figured this out myself, so thanks very very much :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the numbers are the base-10 representation of [Delphi TColor values](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.TColor).

Delphi itself seems to provide some helper functions (e.g. `GetRValue`) to extract the respective read, green and blue values. You have to write something similar in c# yourself.

Having the values you can assemble them into a hex string.

```
string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", redComponent, greenComponent, blueComponent);
```

Simply converting the integer value to a hex-string, padded or not, will most likely not do the right thing.

*UPDATE* as commenter James L. points out, the order of the components is actually different for/in delphi. To generate a `TColor`-like value the order must be:

```
string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", blueComponent, greenComponent, redComponent);
```

Comment: I think your order is backwards.  Red should be #0000FF, green should be #00FF00 and blue should be #FF0000.  So your color order should be changed to Blue Green Red.